# NGINX Wordpress install in subdirectory wrong script URL

Tags: wordpress, nginx, subdirectory

Switching from Apache to NGINX here :)

So I have Site A which sits on the root directory `http://test.fake.com/` and works fine. I also have another Wordpress Site (B) where the root is `http://test.fake.com/b/`

All the front end pages for B load scripts and css like `http://test.fake.com/test.fake.com/b/` which of course is incorrect. When I try to goto the Admin like `http://test.fake.com/wp-admin/` I receive `No input file specified.` as the only output, also the URL changes to `http://test.fake.com/test.fake.com/b/wp-login.php`.

Here is a snippet of my NGINX config where I think the problem lies, please let me know if you need more info and be gentle on a NGINX n00b :P

```
    location /b {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /b/index.php$args;
    }

    location / {
            # Set try_files according WP architecture
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    }
```

Here is a snippet of B's wp-config file where I am setting the URLs

```
define('WP_HOME','http://test.fake.com/b');
define('WP_SITEURL','http:/test.fake.com/b');
```

I have no idea where the error lies :(

Thank you for viewing!

Comment: You have a typo - missing `//` in the `WP_SITEURL` definition

Comment: ...f*&%... that's embarassing; i knew had to be something obvious and silly. Thank you and bless your heart!